# After upgrading to Rails 7, errors[:base] not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

i upgraded my rails app to 7 and see that `errors[:base]` is no longer working and not validating as expected. record is getting saved even if it is invalid.

below is my validation method code

```
def file_validation
    if well_list_file.attached?
      if well_list_file.byte_size > 1000000
        errors[:base] << I18n.t('well_list.size_limit')
      end
      if well_list_file.filename.extension_without_delimiter != 'csv'
        Rails.logger.error "in error"
        errors[:base] << I18n.t('well_list.invalid_csv')
      end
    end
  end
```

controller code below

```
  def create
    @api_csv = ApiCsv.new(api_csv_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @api_csv.save
        format.json { render json: @api_csv, status: :created}
      else
        error_msg = @api_csv.errors.full_messages.join('<br/>')
        format.json { render json: {message: error_msg}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In the console i see `in error` but `save` succeeds.

This was working in `rails 5.2`. Any help in how to fix this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: have updated the question with controller code. thanks

Comment: sorry, I' am asleep this morning -- this was a change in the error model in Rails 6. Need to change << to add.  `self.errors.add(:base,  I18n.t('well_list.size_limit'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not explain why, but testing it myself i was able to reproduce this error, but using:

```
errors.add(:base, 'foo')
```

instead of:

```
errors[:base] << 'foo'
```

works and prevents the record from saving.

Comment: I just posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76000432) about this matter.