# errors.add(:base, 'foo') does not abort save in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, save, ruby-on-rails-7

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706544/after-upgrading-to-rails-7-errorsbase-not-working-as-expected), I confirm that in Rails 7 (differently from Rails 6) only `errors.add(:base, 'foo')` and `errors.add(:base, :invalid, 'foo')` effectively adds errors to a model object. According to the [official documentation [cap. 7.5]](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-base):

> You can add errors to :base when you want to say that the object is invalid, no matter the values of its attributes.

I've always used this fact to *abort* saving objects to the database in `before_create` and  `before_save` callbacks, and it's always worked until Rails 7.

In fact, in Rails 7, a call to [save](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) e.g. `@resource.save` saves the record even if it has `errors[:base]` added to it, which should not happen based on the behavior of older versions of Rails and the common sense of the documentation.

I've also noticed that a model object is *marked* invalid (i.e. not saved) if you add `errors[:base]` in `before_validation` callbacks but neither in `before_create` nor `before_save`.

Any chance to make the model object *really* invalid (i.e. make it to be *not* saved) by adding `errors[:base]` to it in other callbacks than `before_validation`? Or, does the new Rails 7 way to make things changed to use `before_validation` for such a matter? Or, is it a bug?

Comment: Section 7 of the guide is about validation so it is sort of implied that 7.5 applies to the validation phase (i.e. `validates ...` or `validate ...` calls, not even `before_validation` really). It may have worked by accident in `before_create` or `before_save` in the past but I don't think it has ever been guaranteed to work anywhere other than inside validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `throw :abort`, for example:

```rb
before_destroy do
  errors.add(:base, 'records cannot be destroyed')
  throw :abort
end
```

This is described in [Halting Execution](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution) in the Active Record Callbacks documentation.